# Evaluating an integral with unspecified functions $f,g$, given other integrals with these functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Suppose that
>   $$\int_6^8(3f(x)-x)\,\mathrm dx=6$$
>   and
>   $$\int_8^6(2x+4g(x))\,\mathrm dx=-8$$
>   Evaluate
>   $$\int_8^6 (f(x)-5g(x))\,\mathrm dx$$

I have a problem. So, this one question asks me to find the integral of a function, however, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Use the linearity property of integrals, assign variable names to the integrals of the unknown functions $f$ and $g$, and turn this into a linear algebra problem.

Comment: As a first step, you could find out what $\int_8^6 f(x)$ and $\int_8^6 g(x)$ are by splitting up your two given integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you need to perform some basic transformations of integrals, here's how to solve the value of $\newcommand{\dx}{\,\mathrm dx}\int_8^6 f(x)\dx$ below, the same teqnique can be used to solve the second integral.
For finding the final integral we have to transform it into some expression involving $\int_8^6 f(x)\dx$ and $\int_8^6 g(x)\dx$, and since we know the value of these, we can substitute those values in.

---

$$\int_6^8(3f(x)-x)\dx=6$$
The integral of a sum is the sum of the integrals
$$\int_6^83f(x)\,\mathrm dx-\int_6^8x\dx=6$$
The second integral equals $14$
$$\int_6^83f(x)\dx-14=6$$
Since $\int af(x)\dx=a\int f(x)\dx$ for any constant $a$
$$3\int_6^8f(x)\dx=20$$
$$\int_6^8f(x)\dx=\frac{20}3$$
Switching the indexes of a integral, negates the result.
$$\int_8^6f(x)\dx=-\frac{20}3$$

Comment: I got -95/3 as my solution. Is this correct?

Comment: @user1763899 Yes